# By clicking android widget invoke some functions that are present in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I want to know how to link widget and activity in android so that by clicking the widget only call some functios to do work but **Not launch the activity** something like when we click bluetooth in notification bar it just open bluetooth or close bluetooth without entering to that bluetooth app......
Thanks in advance :)
*UPDATED* ::
Below is Main Activity Code.

```
imageFlashlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (finalHasCameraFlash) {
                    if (flashLightStatus)
                        flashLightOff();
                    else
                        flashLightOn();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No flash available on your device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

The Code below is my widget code...

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                             int appWidgetId) {

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
    // Construct an Intent object includes web adresss.
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // In widget we are not allowing to use intents as usually. We have to use PendingIntent instead of 'startActivity'
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


    // Here the basic operations the remote view can do.
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvWidget, pendingIntent);
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

UPDATED : As you can see i want to handle two functions by clicking the widget **Without Entering to the activity just by tapping..**

Comment: You should go try https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#ProviderBroadcasts and come back with a question that has some code example problem in it. That's what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sending Broadcast as

`Intent broadcastIntent=new Intent(this,BroadcastReceiver.class);
//use .getBroadcast instead of getActivity and start a service when u receive this
//broadcast
PendingIntent pendingBroadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 7, broadcastIntent, 0)
//set this pendingIntent on widget`

the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method will do the trick.
Remember to start the service when you receive this broadcast you can also set action on the intent using `broadcastIntent.setAction(YOUR_ACTION)`.

Regards,
Karya

Comment: thank you for coming to answer me but it is not working what i wanted  : |